# Decimal Separator in price woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi everyone I have this configuration in my woocommerce [image]

And in my product I have this [image]

but when I show the price  it return me  "4.95" instead of  "4,95"

I use this to get the price

```
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
```

Any idea!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `wc_price` function to format the number.

```
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
$formatted_price = wc_price( $price );
```

Note: For versions < 2.1.0, use `woocommerce_price`.

Comment: The `woocommerce_price()` is deprecated in favor of `wc_price()`. Almost all functions have been renamed with the shorter `wc_` prefix.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks, I have edited the answer. It's been awhile since I've used woocommerce...