# The loop price is displaying without decimals in Woocommerce archive

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is my code that shows price inside loop:

```
//global $woocommerce;
$sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);

if ( $sale ) :
    if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>

        <span class="price float-left">
            <ins><?php echo $product->get_sale_price() . ' ' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></ins>
            <del><?php echo $product->get_regular_price() . ' ' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ' ' . show_sale_percentage_loop(); ?></del>
        </span>

    <?php endif;  
else : ?>

    <span class="price float-left" style="line-height: 36px;">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><?php echo $product->get_regular_price() . ' ' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></span>
    </span>

<?php endif;
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, prices are displayed unformatted, that's wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Woocommerce do you use?

EDIT: Put a look here: [Decimal Separator in price woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816146/decimal-separator-in-price-woocommerce)